# Solve differential equation with integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I already checked that the ODE isn't exact, and tried to express an integrating factor $\mu$=ax+by but when solving the system of equations I couldn't find answers. I also tried to express $\mu$ as $\mu$(ax+by) but things got even more complicated.

I would really appreciate any tips on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Solving this ODE is possible, but leads to an huge solution. I don't write the calculus and solution because I guess that where is something wrong in the wording of the question, if it is a textbook exercise. Could you edit the textual wording of the problem ant the intermediate steps of calculus from which the ODE comes.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, this is a very introductory problem to ODE so the answers should'nt be very difficult, so there must be something wrong. I will copy the exact question to you.

Comment: If it is an introductory problem about the use of integrating factors, the solution should be very simple. So, there is something fishy. Could you made a screen copy (not re-typed by yourself, but a snapshop) of the textbook page.

Comment: Paco - The integrating factor is simply $e^{2x}$.

Comment: Samjoe, taking this integrating factor leads me to different partial derivatives, so you must be mistaking

Comment: @Paco Lopez : Sorry I cannot see how this ODE can be used as a simple example for integrating factor method. Of course, one can use another method to solve the ODE (not simple again). But it should not be in the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\dfrac{d\rho}{d\tau}=\dfrac{1-2\rho-(1-\eta^2)\tau}{\rho}$

$\dfrac{d\rho}{d\tau}=\dfrac{(\eta^2-1)\tau+1}{\rho}-2$

Let $u=\dfrac{\rho}{(\eta^2-1)\tau+1}$ ,

Then $\rho=((\eta^2-1)\tau+1)u$

$\dfrac{d\rho}{d\tau}=((\eta^2-1)\tau+1)\dfrac{du}{d\tau}+(\eta^2-1)u$

$\therefore((\eta^2-1)\tau+1)\dfrac{du}{d\tau}+(\eta^2-1)u=\dfrac{1}{u}-2$

$((\eta^2-1)\tau+1)\dfrac{du}{d\tau}=\dfrac{1}{u}-2-(\eta^2-1)u$

$((\eta^2-1)\tau+1)\dfrac{du}{d\tau}=-\dfrac{(\eta^2-1)u^2+2u-1}{u}$